# Архитектура расширяемого приложения

Tags: c#, архитектура, шаблоны-проектирования

Есть несколько C#-проектов (WindowsForms), и нужно их соединить в одно приложение.

Каждый из уже существующих проектов должен быть оформлен в виде плагина к этому новому приложению, назовем его PluginContainer. Разумеется, эти плагины ничего не должны знать друг о друге и никак не взаимодействуют. Главное приложение при запуске должно загрузить эти плагины в отдельных вкладках. Сам плагин должен состоять из файла представления, файла логики и xml-файла с описанием плагина.

Главная проблема - отсутствие опыта в проектировании таких систем и вообще опыта работы с  ООП, не понимаю, с какого конца подойти. Смотрел в сторону MEF, прочитал несколько статей, но пока не могу оценить, насколько этот подход целесообразен.

Если без MEF, то, как я понял, в PluginContainer я должен описать несколько классов, которые обрабатывают плагины. Может, существует какой-то паттерн, который может мне помочь?

В общем, если кто-то имеет опыт в проектировании таких систем, то было бы очень интересно узнать, как это все грамотнее сделать.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Приложение с плагинной архитектурой состоит из двух частей: хоста и собственно плагинов.
В .NET хост обязательно должен содержать интерфейсную сборку, в которой объявлен интерфейс плагина. Плагин представляет собой сборку, снабжённую манифестом (манифест необязателен, но с ним будет быстрее работать), в которой находится класс, реализующий интерфейс, объявленный в интерфейсной сборке хоста. Манифест должен представлять собой файл с расширением, известным хосту, в котором записано имя сборки, которую требуется загрузить, и, если требуется, конкретные типы.

При старте хост должен пройтись по директории, в которую предполагается помещать плагины, и открыть все файлы манифестов. После этого сборки, указанные в манифестах, загружаются вызовом `Assembly.Load`, `Assembly.LoadFrom` или `Assenbly.LoadFile`. При этом, если путь, по которому грузятся плагины, отличается от каталога приложения, этот путь надо добавить в список путей поиска сборок вызовом `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AppendPrivatePath`. Затем для каждой сборки вызывается метод `GetTypes()` который возвращает список типов, объявленных в сборке. Каждый тип необходимо проверить на реализацию интерфейса плагина, вызвав `typeof(IMyPlugin).IsAssignableFrom(current_type)`, и, если тип реализует интерфейс плагина, создать экземпляр интерфейса плагина вызовом `Activator.CreateInstance`. В результате формируется список экземпляров интерфейса, с которым что-то можно делать.

В Вашем случае я бы порекомендовал в манифестах указывать файл представления (насколько я понимаю, Вы под представлением имеете в виду сборку с кодом представления), а в интерфейсе плагина сделать свойство, возвращающее контрол, который требуется отобразить на вкладке. Сборка с логикой должна помещаться рядом со сборкой с представлением и, по идее, должна загружаться автоматически при обращении к ней из сборки с пользовательским интерфейсом плагина.

Comment: Большое спасибо за развернутый ответ, думаю, так и сделаю.

Comment: Да, вот ещё что. В дотнете есть стандартная библиотека `System.AddIn` для этого. Правда, мне не понравилась.

Comment: Еще вот нашел неплохое руководство по созданию простейшей архитектуры, по сути, написано как раз то, что Вы мне объясняли, плюс исходники, вдруг кому пригодится.
http://forum.cbsystematics.com/showthread.cbsx?t=298

Comment: Хороший совет! Сам делал примерно так-же :]

Answer (score 11):

Найдено на просторах интернета:

[Практическое руководство по созданию Plug-in архитектуры на C#](http://codingcraft.ru/readarticle.php?article_id=7)

[Книга MEF](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/net/95809/), [Простейший пример MEF](http://sotnyk.com/2011/07/15/prosteyshiy-primer-mef/)

[Пример системы плагинов](http://www.codenet.ru/progr/csharp/PluginSystem.php)

Comment: Спасибо большое, толковый материал.

Comment: Спасибо за ссылки.

Answer (score 4):

Есть готовая библиотека позволяющая организовать плагины для приложения, называется [MEF](http://mef.codeplex.com/).

Comment: MEF уже давно [часть стандартной поставки](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648.aspx) .NET framework